# Filter out subpages with regex in Gatsby GraphiQL

Tags: regex, graphql, gatsby

I need to filter out subpages in Gatsby GraphiQL, i. e. I need to get a list of pages without subpages.

Here is my query for the opposite (getting the subpages only):

```
query {
  allMdx(filter: {fields: {slug: {regex: "/blog/.+$/"} }}) {
    nodes {
      id
      frontmatter {
        title
      }
      fields {
        slug
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I change this query to get a list of pages without subpages?

Thank you very much in advance.